# Gazebo unable to launch empty world

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi~everyone

I installed ROS fuerte in Ubuntu 12.04 and I tried to launch the empty world

```
  roslaunch  gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch
```

I got the following error message:

```
  Error [Transport.cc:102] Unable to get topic namespaces in [50] tries.
  Error [Node.cc:68] No namespace found
```

/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui: line 2:  5106 segmentation fault   (core dumped) `rospack find gazebo`/gazebo/bin/gzclient -g `rospack find gazebo`/lib/libgazebo_ros_paths_plugin.so
[gazebo_gui-3] process has died [pid 5099, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/qxesqxes/.ros/log/326a199c-ec38-11e1-a2f0-c446195a3b7d/gazebo_gui-3.log].
log file: /home/qxesqxes/.ros/log/326a199c-ec38-11e1-a2f0-c446195a3b7d/gazebo_gui-3*.log

Your help would be much appreciated, thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41985/gazebo-unable-to-launch-empty-world/) by [Eric](https://answers.ros.org/users/2016/eric/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-08-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having this same issue - Fuerte installed on Ubuntu 12.04 keeps having a segmentation fault when I run:

```
roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_empty_world.launch
```

I get:

```
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.0.2

Copyright (C) 2011 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, Andrew Howard, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master.Msg Waiting for master[ INFO] [ros.roscpp]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...

Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://localhost:11345
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  153 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
  Serial number of failed request:  12
  Current serial number in output stream:  12

Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://localhost:11345
Error [Transport.cc:102] Unable to get topic namespaces in [50] tries.
Error [Node.cc:68] No namespace found
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui: line 2:  9548 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) `rospack find gazebo`/gazebo/bin/gzclient -g `rospack find gazebo`/lib/libgazebo_ros_paths_plugin.so
[gazebo_gui-2] process has died [pid 9545, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/dave/.ros/log/806e1d36-13f3-11e2-8ce7-3c075420f805/gazebo_gui-2.log].
log file: /home/dave/.ros/log/806e1d36-13f3-11e2-8ce7-3c075420f805/gazebo_gui-2*.log
^C[gazebo-1] killing on exit
[gazebo-1] escalating to SIGTERM
```

---

Originally posted by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) with karma: 1396 on 2012-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) on 2012-11-05**:
You may hae a problem with your opengl.  Does glxinfo give a useful response?